# How many ways are there for 50 people to divide them into three groups, A, B and C such that each consists of 20, 18, and 12, respectively?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have tried to solve this problem but I can not figure out where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT: After another attempt I am leaning towards the answer $\frac{50!}{20!18!12!}$

EDIT2: I know that the answer that I arrived at is correct but I still do not understand why it is correct.

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you have tried till now. People at MSE can help you better if you show your work and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: yes you are right .. well done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, your answer is correct.

We can select $20$ of the $50$ people for group $A$ in $\binom{50}{20}$ ways, $18$ of the remaining $30$ people for group $B$ in $\binom{30}{18}$, and all $12$ of the remaining $12$ people for group $C$ in $\binom{12}{12}$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting $20$ people for group $A$, $18$ people for group $B$, and $12$ people for group $C$ is 
$$\binom{50}{20}\binom{30}{18}\binom{12}{12} = \frac{50!}{20!30!} \cdot \frac{30!}{18!12!} \cdot \frac{12!}{12!0!} = \frac{50!}{20!18!12!0!} = \frac{50!}{20!18!12!}$$
as you found.

Answer (score 1):

We can split them this way:

We line everyone up in a line (we will get $50!$ this way), then we choose the first 20 into $A$, the next 18 into $B$, and the last 12 into $C$.

Then inside $A, B, C$ we should remove the 'duplicates', i.e. the number of permutations inside the group, which is $20!,18!,12!$ respectively for $A, B, C$.

Hence we arrive at your answer $\frac{50!}{20!18!12!}$.